# Customizing/Architecting AWS ELB to have Zero Downtime

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-elb

So other day we faced an issue where one of the instance behind our application load balancer failed Instance Status Check and System Check. It took about 10 sec (the minimum we can get) for our ELB to detect this and mark the instance as "unhealthy", however we lost some amount of traffic in those 10 seconds as the ELB kept routing traffic to the unhealthy instance. Is there a solution where we can avoid literally any downtime or am I being too unrealistic?

Comment: 10 seconds is the minimum that AWS allows us to set in Health Checks. Cant go further down than that according to AWS Support.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm sure this isn't the answer you want to hear, but in order to minimize traffic loss on your systems if 10s is not tolerable, you'll need to implement your own health check/load balancing solution. My organization has systems where packet loss is unacceptable as well, and that's what we needed to do.

This solution is twofold.

1. You need to implement your own load-balancing infrastructure. We chose to use Route53 weighted record sets (TTL of 1s, we'll get back to this) with equal weight for each server
2. Launch an ECS container instance per load-balanced EC2 instance whose sole purpose is to health check. It runs both DNS and IP health checks (requests library in python) and will add/remove the Route53 weighted record real-time as it sees an issue.

In our testing, however, we discovered that while the upstream DNS servers from Route53 honor the 1 second TTL upon removal of a DNS record, they "blacklist" that record (FQDN + IP combo) from coming back up again for up to 10 minutes (we get variance of resolution times from 1m-10m). So you'll be able to failover quickly, but you must take into account it will take up to 10 minutes for the re-addition of the record to be honored.